# How to set particular value of bootstrap button dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have one bootstrap button dropdown where i need when form data should save after that in jquery script i want to show default value in this dropdown i am not loading the page happening in client side only.
Below is my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="btn-group" style="width:160px">
  <button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Select Gender <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Select Gender</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Male</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Female</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So in this code i need once form submitted and shows value from success of ajax call there i need to set dropdown value of first list which value is "Select Gender".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follow

```
$("button.dropdown-toggle").html('Select Gender <span class="caret"></span>');
```

Put this code in your AJAX Success event.

Comment: Thanks Hemal it's working for me. i am marking your answer.

Comment: yes your answer is correct. will give you vote for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
$(".btn-group button.dropdown-toggle").html('Select Gender <span class="caret"></span>');
```

to reset the HTML of dropdown button